# Bibliography in beamer-metropolis

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, natbib, beamer-metropolis, bibliographystyle

I'm using beamer slides, and trying to generate the bibliography, but the output I get prints only the item label, not the actual bibliographic information (e.g., "surname, name year."

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}


 \title{Title}
 \author{Authore}
 \institute{Institute}

 \begin{document}

  \maketitle

  \begin{frame}{Frame}
  \cite{test}
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
      \frametitle{References}
      \bibliographystyle{apalike}
      \bibliography{test.bib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The test.bib is just one entry:

```
@article{test,
    Author = {Test, Name},
    Journal = {Journal},
    Pages = {1 - 193},
    Title = {Longtext},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {1000}
  }
```

Comment: Did you run biber?

Comment: Replacing with \usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber,    style=authoryear-icomp,
useprefix=true]{biblatex} prints "Author, year", but no parentehses around "year", and no bibliography printed at the end of the presentation. (I have \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
      \frametitle{References}
      \bibliographystyle{apalike}
      \bibliography{test.bib}
\end{frame})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- the biblatex syntax to add a bib file is `\addbibressource{<filename>.bib}`. Place this in the preamble
- the biblatex syntax to choose a style is via the `style=...` key in the package options, thus remove `\bibliographystyle` from your document
- to print the references add `\printbinliography` to the frame where you want the references
- to add `(...)` around the year, use `\citet` instead of `\cite`
- don't forget to compile with biber instead of bibtex

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}
  \citet{knuth:ct}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```